# La variante orthographique sans majuscule de « coup d'État » est-elle acceptable ?

Tags: majuscules, politique, fréquence-utilisation

Je révisais les définitions de ce que constitue un *coup d'État* et Wiktionnaire semble la seule source donnant « [coup d'état](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/coup_d%E2%80%99%C3%A9tat) » (sans la majuscule à *état*) comme variante orthographique de [*coup d'État*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/coup_d%E2%80%99%C3%89tat#fr). J'ai tout d'abord pensé que la variante était peut-être plus ancienne mais Wiktionnaire donne un [exemple](https://www.journaldemontreal.com/2020/11/21/coup-detat-rate) de cette année (vraisemblablement modifié depuis). Par ailleurs [*Larousse en ligne*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9tat/31316) explique « avec une majuscule quand il s'agit du pays, de la nation ou de son autorité souveraine ».

Pourquoi la variante orthographique peut-elle se justifier ou non ; s'agit-il d'un autre sens de la locution (si oui, lequel) ou d'une erreur orthographique ; la comparaison de la fréquence d'emploi révèle-t-elle quoi que ce soit d'intéressant (géographie, époque etc.) ?

Comment: p.s. «... de ce que constitue un coup d'État ». Je devais utiliser _qui_ ou je pensais au verbe _consister_ ?

Comment: La majuscule signe le nom d'une personne ou d'une société, Pour une société on signale la cible du coup, avec la minuscule on constate ce qu'il en résulte : Après ce coup d'***É**tat*, le pays était dans un sale ***é**tat*, alors que pour une personne « Le coup du père François » indique la technique utilisée par ce dernier.

Comment: @Personne Mais qu'en serait-il du « coup d'état du père François » ?

Comment: Incohérent : une technique qui utilise un *coup* n'est pas un état, mais un procédé pour agir (une action induit un changement d'état) : https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/faire-le-coup-du-pere-francois

Comment: @Personne Oui, je sais que _coup de_ donne une technique. Je parle d'état comme de la variante orthographique d'État. J'essaye de nous ramener au sujet.

Comment: Abandonner cette idée « Je parle d'état comme de la variante orthographique d'État. » et attribuer le **é** à une erreur typographique, à une faute d'orthographe évitera la confusion ou une lecture erronée pour rétablir le « coup d'**É**tat du père François »

Answer (score 1):

Un coup d'État se rapporte bien à l'État et non par exemple à un changement d'état.

Il faut donc toujours la majuscule (et normalement aussi l'accent, mais c'est une autre histoire).

Ce site confirme et donne de nombreux exemples et contre-exemples :

https://archive.ph/20120701102722/http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1285&D=%C9tat

Answer (score -1):

Je ne crois pas à Wiktionnaire, d'une façon générale.

J'ai vérifié les prétendues « sources » et le livre de Weisgerber, « Au seuil du Maroc moderne » utilise, en réalité une majuscule.

Ce qui aurait pu, comme moi, vous mettre la puce à l'oreille c'est que dans la page Wikitruc la citation contient une autre majuscule. Regardez-bien:
« Par un hardi coup d’état Si Ahmed Ben Moussa s'était alors emparé du grand-vizirat et des rênes du gouvernement, »

Que vient faire la majuscule à « Si » ?

Rien, justement. Et je suspecte une erreur de reconnaissance automatique lors de la numérisation.

Pour preuve, voici une copie du livre:
https://books.google.fr/books?id=TlVyAAAAMAAJ&q=par+un+hardi+coup+d%E2%80%99%C3%A9tat+si+ahmed+ben+moussa+s%27%C3%A9tait+alors+empar%C3%A9+du+grand-vizirat+et+des+r%C3%AAnes+du+gouvernement&dq=par+un+hardi+coup+d%E2%80%99%C3%A9tat+si+ahmed+ben+moussa+s%27%C3%A9tait+alors+empar%C3%A9+du+grand-vizirat+et+des+r%C3%AAnes+du+gouvernement&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwighPvLt8HvAhVx6uAKHdClBuAQ6wEwAHoECAUQBQ

Ensuite l'autre citation:
« Un coup d'état est la prise de contrôle illégitime et subite d'un gouvernement par un petit groupe d'individus. — (Loïc Tassé, « Cour d'état raté », Le journal de Montréal, 21 novembre 2020) »

Regardez le titre: « Cour d'état raté ». CouR.

Comment prendre ces références au sérieux?

Cela dit j'ai vérifié la Revue des deux mondes sur Gallica et effectivement l'ouvrage original se dispense de majuscule. Sachant que la phrase suivante se dispense de T à « mécontens » (sic), donc le contexte me fait dire que de nos jours l'usage est d'utiliser toujours la majuscule.

Comment: Oui mais voyez cette [édition-là](https://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&id=-MIvAAAAIAAJ&dq=par+un+hardi+coup+d%E2%80%99%C3%A9tat+si+ahmed+ben+moussa+s%27%C3%A9tait+alors+empar%C3%A9+du+grand-vizirat+et+des+r%C3%AAnes+du+gouvernement&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=hardi+coup+). L'article de Tassé n'est plus un exemple, ils ont [modifié](https://www.journaldemontreal.com/2020/11/21/coup-detat-rate). Le Wiktionnaire est entièrement utile à mon avis et votre propos, considérant l'édition sans la majuscule, me semble bien injuste, les gens ont le droit à l'erreur et il s'agit d'une oeuvre collaborative.

Comment: Que vient faire _Si_ ? Je ne sais pas, on le trouve [en anglais](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g293734-d610173-r172884150-Palacio_da_Bahia-Marrakech_Marrakech_Safi.html) aussi... Il vaut mieux vérifier.

Comment: _Mécontens_ est une ancienne graphie ([Ac.4](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/m%C3%A9content)) ; le dernier para. de la réponse pourrait laisser entendre qu'il y a erreur ou ne prend pas le temps d'expliquer que l'emploi sans la majuscule pourrait représenter un truc ancien et peu étayé.