# Le coup d'État, le putsch et le pronunciam(i)ento : nuances d'emploi de ces synonymes ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, synonymes, emprunts, connotation, fréquence-utilisation

Au TLFi on dit que « [putsch](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/putsch) » (de l'allemand) est synonyme de « [coup](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coup) d'État » (bizarrement, on n'a pas employé la [majuscule](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/43988/25619)) et de « [pronunciam(i)ento](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pronunciamiento) » (de l'espagnol).

Mais on a un exemple où l'on emploie deux des termes dans une même phrase :

> Le vieux La Fayette lui-même, revenu à ses ardeurs de 1789, rêvait
> d'un **pronunciamiento** à la manière espagnole: le **coup d'État** du 2
> décembre se préparait dès ce moment-là (Bainville, *Hist. fr.*, t.2,
> 1924, p.153) (au TLFi)

Ou un autre où l'on place le terme entre guillemets :

> Nous voyons les affaires civiles et militaires dans un état d'anarchie
> dont certains énergumènes, ou intrigants, ou dévots de Vichy, ou même
> agents de l'ennemi, profitent pour pratiquer le sabotage et créer, à
> tout moment, une atmosphère de « **putsch** » (De Gaulle, *Mém. guerre*,
> 1956, p. 494) (au TLFi)

S'agit-il vraiment de synonymes ? Peut-on présenter une systématisation des nuances d'emploi et la langue d'origine des termes y est-elle pertinente ; y a-t-il des différences de connotation ? Peut-on classer les trois termes selon leur fréquence d'emploi ? Incidemment, le premier exemple reflète-t-il simplement la richesse du vocabulaire de l'auteur ; dans le deuxième exemple l'auteur veut-il simplement attirer l'attention sur le fait qu'il s'agit là d'un emprunt ?

Comment: *Pronunciamiento* est utilisé pour évoquer des faits en hispanophonie, *putsch* pour les autres pays, tous les deux évoquent des faits semblables, le premier est inconnu de la majorité des francophones sans lien avec la langue espagnole, le second est utilisé par tous les professionnels de l'information  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=putsch%2Cpronunciamiento%2Cpronunciamento&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cputsch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpronunciamiento%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpronunciamento%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

Personnellement, on m'a appris qu'un putsch était toujours un coup d’État *militaire* (ce qui ne couvre pas le cas où un homme politique ferait arrêter les membres de l'opposition par la police, par exemple). Cela dit, les journalistes parlent souvent de *putsch militaire*, donc je ne sais pas si la règle que j'ai apprise est valide.

Pour ce qui est de *pronunciamiento*, je ne l'ai jamais entendu utilisé, mais ce serait logique que ce soit utilisé plutôt pour les pays hispanophones.

Answer (score 1):

Putsch peut désigner n’importe quel changement brusque de pouvoir au sein d’une entité (ex : Carlos Ghosn dénonce un putsch au sein de Renault). Un coup d’état est un putsch dans un état.